# Search functionality in Bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have successfully created Bot in MS Teams, now there is a requirement where the user needs to select any one option out of approx. 100 options (I know providing those many buttons in MS Teams UI is not feasible considering usability). I have looked for available options in PromptDialog class [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs) but couldn't find suitable solution. Can I add search functionality same like we have in the web application? (see attachment). Any help in this is highly appreciated.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few options you have here.

1. You could use a list entity in LUIS.  Although it does not sound as if you are using LUIS already.
2. You could use [scorable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers) or an if statement in your ActivityType.Message section to catch the word "search" (or something similar) then implement logic to search a collection of some sort based on the user's next message. great video on scorables [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnU3lPHhv88)
3. You could create a card with a text box input that you could implement logic to use that to search some sort of collection.

   There is node/c# versions of all of this

   [rich cards samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards)
   [Rich cards doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments)
   [Adaptive cards doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots)
   [Adaptive cards sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-AdaptiveCards)

   I'm sure there is more solutions others can add as well

Comment: Hello JasonSowers, Thank you for your reply. This is really a very useful information. I will try and if any help needed then will get back.